# How to calculate Storage when ftping to MainFrame

Tags: ftp, storage, mainframe, jcl

How can I calculate storage when FTPing to MainFrame? I was told LRECL will always remain '80'. Not sure how I can calculate PRI and SEC dynamically based on the file size...

```
   QUOTE SITE LRECL=80 RECFM=FB CY PRI=100 SEC=100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the site has SMS, you shouldn't need to, but if you need to calculate the number of tracks is the size of the file in bytes divided by 56,664, or the number of cylinders is the size of the file in bytes divided by 849,960.  In either case, you would round up.

Comment: Those magic numbers in your answer depend on the type of disk file storage on the mainframe; 3370, 3380, 3390, 3390 in 3380 compatibility mode.  User1106741 needs to get those numbers from his mainframe developers.

Comment: I wasn't aware those older units were still made.  My knowledge of physical hardware that IBM makes is limited.  The OP could always allocate in blocks and specify a block size to get the exact number of bytes needed regardless of device type.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately IBM's FTP server does not support the newer space allocation specifications in number of records (the JCL parameter AVGREC=U/M/K plus the record length as the first specification in the SPACE parameter).

However, there is an alternative, and that is to fall back on one of the lesser-used SPACE parameters - the blocksize specification. I will assume 3390 disk types for simplicity, and standard data sets.

For fixed-length records, you want to calculate the largest number that will fit in half a track (27994 bytes), because z/OS only supports block sizes up to 32760. Since you are dealing with 80-byte records, that number is 27290. Divide your file size by that number and that will give you the number of blocks. Then in a SITE server command, specify

```
SITE BLKSIZE=27920 LRECL=80 RECFM=FB BLOCKS=27920 PRI=calculated# SEC=a_little_extra
```

This is equivalent to SPACE=(27920,(calculated#,a_little_extra)).

z/OS space allocation calculates the number of tracks required and rounds up to the nearest track boundary.

For variable-length records, if your reading application can handle it, always use BLKSIZE=27994. The reason I have the warning about the reading application is that even today there are applications from ISVs that still have strange hard-coded maximum variable length blocks such as 12K.

If you are dealing with PDSEs, always use BLKSIZE=32760 for variable-length and the closest-to-32760 for fixed-length in your specification (32720 for FB/80), but calculate requirements based on BLKSIZE=4096. PDSEs are strange in their underlying layout; the physical records are 4096 bytes, which is because there is some linear data set VSAM code that handles the physical I/O.